# Git status and git diff show no changes

Tags: git

I made changes to my code and typed:

`git status`

Which returned

`Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/branch_name'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Then I typed

`git diff`

Which didn't print out anything...

Can someone help? It should be showing me files that were changed...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your changes are in the exclusion ? your .gitignore file ?

Comment: ... did you save the files?

Comment: they're not in .gitignore and i did save the files

Comment: Are you calling `git status` from the correct working directory?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you changed a file listed in `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`. See [Github's "Ignoring Files"](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) documentation for more information.

Alternatively is it possible you already committed and pushed your changes? Check with `git log` or `gitk` (if installed).

Comment: hi - i checked .gitignore and the files i changed are not being ignored.

Comment: Check if you committed? `git log` and maybe `gitk` (if installed) might help.

Answer (score 0):

When you type git status it compare the content of your working directory to the staging area and the staging are to the repository.

In your case all your files are commited so no changes are tracked.

---

Diff will print out the difference (content) of the changes which status only print summary

Comment: can i un-commit somehow?

Comment: of course you can. Read all about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --soft HEAD^` solved the issue... i'm not 100% sure why.

Comment: That means you already committed it. And you already pushed it to the remote.